# How to list all value in array one by one for many items from json URL

Tags: php, json, api, loops

```
<?php
$id = '2422414574';
$json = file_get_contents("http://xxxxxx.com/api.php?token=xxxx&id=xxxx");
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->phim[0]->filmName . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[0]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[0]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[1]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[1]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[2]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[2]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[3]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[3]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[4]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[4]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[5]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[5]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[6]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[6]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[7]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[7]->id . "<br/>";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[xxxx]->name . " - ";
echo $data->phim[0]->epsList[xxxx]->id . "<br/>";
echo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see, I have to repeat 1 code in many time. Is there any short way to do this without repeat code?
For example, I want to get all values from **id** and **name** from [this URL](http://xxxxxx.com/api.php?token=xxxx&id=xxxx), which have 24 items. That means I have to repeat code in 24 times :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about foreach()?

```
foreach($data->phim as $phim)
{
  echo $phim->filmName . "<br/>";
  foreach($phim->epsList as $epsList)
  {
    echo $epsList->name . " - ";
    echo $epsList->id . "<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 55

Comment: `$phim[0]` instead of `$phim`. Right idea though.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's all i need :*

Comment: @Nicky why two `foreach()` when one can do the things?

Comment: There are not only one phim.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over it using a foreach loop. This is one of the basic functions of PHP and there are many tutorials for it.